# Missing values in current row that apear in prevoius rows need to be retained

Tags: sas

```
DATA HAVE;
INPUT POLID PRODID TOSNUM PREMID;
DATALINES;
13102100207 310 0 1
13102100207 310 0 20
13102100207 310 0 21
13102100207 310 1 1
13102100207 310 1 2
13102100207 310 1 3
13102100207 310 1 20
13102100207 310 1 21
13102100207 310 2 1
13102100207 310 2 2
13102100207 310 2 3
13102100207 310 2 20
13102100207 310 2 21
13102100207 310 3 1
13102100207 310 3 2
13102100207 310 3 20
13102100207 310 3 21
;RUN;
```

as can bee seen from the above set,
I have polid (together with prodid and tosnum) with different premids.
for tosnum = 0 I have 3 different premids.
For tosnum = tosnum = 1 I have 5 different premids,

and you can see for tosnum = 3  I have 4 different premids (premid = 3 is missing)

what I need to do is ,
to keep the premid that existed in previous rows, 
so tosnum  = 3 will be kept for premid  >= 3.

I thought of doing a loop with set operations (Minus and than Uninon all)
but I am sure there is a better and efficient solution...

Your help is very much apprediated.

Answer (score 0):

OK guys.
This  is what I did eventually:

```
proc sort data=have out=have;
by polid prodid TOSNUM premid;
run;

proc sql;
select min(TOSNUM), max(TOSNUM) ,  max(TOSNUM) - min(TOSNUM)  into: min_TOSNUM, :max_TOSNUM, :diff
from have
group by polid, prodid;
quit;


%macro fictive_premid (min_TOSNUM = , diff = );
%do i =  &min_TOSNUM %to %eval(&diff-1) ;
    proc sql;
create table fictive_premid_t as
select * from 
(
select polid, prodid, %eval(&i+1) as TOSNUM, premid, 1 as FICTIVE_IND
from have
where TOSNUM = &i
except
select polid, prodid, %eval(&i+1) as TOSNUM , premid,  1 as FICTIVE_IND
from have
where TOSNUM = %eval(&i+1)
)
union 
select polid, prodid,%eval(&i+1) as TOSNUM, premid, 0 as FICTIVE_IND
from have
where TOSNUM = %eval(&i+1);
quit;

proc append base=fictive_premid data=fictive_premid_t; run;

%end;

proc sql;
insert into fictive_premid (POLID,  PRODID,  TOSNUM,  PREMID, FICTIVE_IND)
select a.*, 0 from HAVE as a
where TOSNUM = &min_TOSNUM;
quit;

%mend;


%fictive_premid (min_TOSNUM = &min_TOSNUM, diff = &diff );
```